# How do I rotate a CGImageRef?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIImage` that appears to be oriented the correct way when my iPad is held in portrait, but when I get the `CGImageRef` associated with it, the `CGImageRef` is rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise. After some Googling, I've learned that this is because the `CGImageRef` has no orientation data unlike the `UIImage`. I need to view and modify some of the pixels in the `CGImageRef`, and I'm currently doing this by directly accessing the rawData variable (image is a UIImage*):

```
CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); //maybe make ...Gray();
unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
```

However, in order for me to properly modify the pixel data stored in rawData, I need the CGImageRef to be in the correct orientation. How can I rotate the `CGImageRef` 90 degrees clockwise and then access rawData (the pixel information)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
CGImageRef imageRef = [sourceImage CGImage];
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceInfo = CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef);


CGContextRef bitmap;

if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp || sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
    bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, targetWidth, targetHeight, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, bitmapInfo);

} else {
    bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, targetHeight, targetWidth, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, bitmapInfo);

}   

if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, radians(90));
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, 0, -targetHeight);

} else if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, radians(-90));
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, -targetWidth, 0);

} else if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
    // NOTHING
} else if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, targetWidth, targetHeight);
    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, radians(-180.));
}

CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), imageRef);
CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
```

Comment: Why does the target height and width need to be flipped for left/right orientations? Also, why does the bitmap need to be translated?

Comment: Where does bitmapInfo come from? You should probably release the CGContextRef also.